# Nuxt js Google Tag Manager JQuery problem

Tags: vuejs2, google-tag-manager, nuxt.js

I have installed @nuxtjs/google-tag-manager module and configure it. Then i start project in production and jquery stopped working. I mean no clicks and other jquery events working.

Have anyone else experienced the same issue? What did i do wrong?

I use latest version of nuxt 2.

Comment: Check error log..and anyway it's bad idea to use jQuery on nuxt site

Comment: I know it is bad. It is not my project. Sure i have checked error logs and problem is that when i use tag manager plugin, other assets for example bootstrap doesn't see jquery.

Comment: JS assets are loaded from nuxt.config. Assets are loaded mostly from cdn. What happens is that google tag manager asynchronously loads its jquery, but i don't know why other assets doesn't see jquery. Site uses jquery 2.2.4 and gtm loads 2.1.4 version. I think version isn't problem here